# Active Admin not parsing html correctly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, blogs

I'm creating a blog with rails using activeadmin and active_admin_editor.  The Blog table is simple:

```
title:string
content:text
```

When I add a blog post it shows the html tags, I need the tags to actually be parsed so blog posts actually look like a real html page.

I've also already tried a migration to change the content column to 'text' instead of a string... that didn't help.

This is what my posts look like right now:
[image]

What have I done wrong or missed here to get the html tags to render correctly?

** UPDATE **
After a suggestion to get the activeadmin view working, I'm still left with the raw html in the user view (non-admin user that can only view the blog)

[image]

Comment: Use `html_safe` and hope it actually is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customize the ActiveAdmin pages into admin/post.rb with something like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  # ....
  index do
    # ...
    column (:content) { |post| raw(post.content) }
    # ...
  end
  show do
    # ...
    row (:content) { |post| raw(post.content) }
    # ...
  end
end
```

For your own views (ex: posts/show.html.erb), just use:

```
raw(@post.content)
```

instead of

```
@post.content
```

in your own view. 'raw' will show the content "as is", without escaping the HTML (which Rails is doing by default).

Comment: That works for the activeadmin side of things, but doesn't change the view a user would see... that still appears as raw html.  *Updated Original Post with Screenshot*

Comment: Updated to include an example

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer here, which I found looking for a solution, is outdated now. The following code should get you there instead:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  # ....
  index do
    # ...
    column :content do |post| 
      raw(post.content)
    end
    # ...
  end
  show do
    # ...
    row :content do |post| 
      raw(post.content)
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```